# Iluminação dentro de uma sala no Blender

Tags: 3d, blender

Estou começando no *Blender* agora, deve ser uma pergunta simples.

Fiz uma sala, com um cubo esticado para o chão, depois alguns cortes no cubo para serem as bases das paredes e um extrude para todas subirem com a mesma altura.
Para fechar o teto utilizei apenas uma face nova, selecionando duas bordas e pressionando *F*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora quando entro na sala dando zoom no painel *3dView*, fica tudo escuro lá dentro, mesmo eu colocando lâmpadas dentro da sala.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando renderiza com *F12* a luz funciona e o interior aparece iluminado, mas para eu mexer no painel *3DView* fica tudo escuro.

Alguém sabe o que fazer para as luzes afetarem a cena sem ter que renderizar?
Alguma forma que eu consiga enxergar a parte de dentro.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ah tem um só de blender, valeu!

Comment: Fora de escopo. Está pergunta não se trata de programação.

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos @SérgioS.Filho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser que o problema esteja na sua placa de vídeo. Tente atualizar o *driver* de sua placa.

Um amigo do trabalho passou pelo mesmo problema e ao atualizar o *driver* o problema foi resolvido, não tenho experiência com o Blender pra indicar outras possíveis causas mas acho interessante a tentativa.

Comment: Obrigado, Leonardo. Essa thread é antiga mas o problema era exatamente este, driver de video... Esqueci de responder aqui.

Comment: Olá Leonardo. Sua resposta está correta, porém a explicação está muito simplista. Você poderia editar sua resposta para deixá-la um pouco mais completa? Procure sempre se expressar de forma mais completa, pesquisar antes de publicar a resposta, colocar referências, etc. Isso evita que você seja algum dia, negativado nas respostas, e suas respostas sejam sinalizadas como de baixa qualidade.

Comment: Não entendi os comentários dizendo que não responde a minha pergunta, o problema era exatamente o driver da placa de video e não o blender! Eu demorei pra descobrir isso...

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos @SérgioS.Filho.